# Decrypt all usernames found in an ArrayList of users?

Tags: java, encryption, arraylist

I'm working on a simple login system on Java and I'm having trouble decrypting all usernames stored in an ArrayList of Users (Users.java contains int userId, String username, and String password) so that I can compare them with new registered usernames to check for duplicates and send back a false boolean over the server to the client if the username already exists.

I'm not sure on how I can decrypt every username at once? I've tested my decryption method on individual usernames and the decryption works fine. What I've tried so far is...

An advanced for-loop to temporarily add all decrypted usernames, with another advanced for-loop to go through the temp ArrayList and check if the new already decrypted username is found in that ArrayList;

```
String dUsername = aes.decrypt(eUsername);            
boolean isRegistered = false;     

List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
for (Users users : usersList) {
    temp.add(aes.decrypt(users.getUsername()));
}

for (String usernames : temp) {
    if (!usernames.equals(dUsername))   
        isRegistered = true;
}
```

This doesn't work.

eUsername is the encrypted username, and isRegistered is going to send true/false to the client depending on if the username is a duplicate or not. How could I get get all the usernames in the usersList ArrayList, and decrypt all the values so I can compare them with the decrypted eUsername (dUsername)? Is it possible?

Comment: `if (!usernames.equals(dUsername))` should probably be `if (usernames.equals(dUsername))`, right?

Comment: It's an "enhanced for loop" or a "foreach loop". Certainly not an "advanced for loop"...

Comment: Could you define 'doesn't work'?  What do you expect vs what are you getting?  Side note: you can do the comparison in the first loop and skip the whole temp array.

Comment: Artjom, why's that? I thought the way I was doing it would translate to there being no duplicates so the person can be registered. Boris, that was an auto-correct.

Comment: Thomas, doesn't work as in it just says there's duplicates even if the username isn't currently in the ArrayList. What I expect is to compare the new username to be registered with the usernames already registered and stored in the ArrayList. The big thing is that the values in the ArrayList are encrypted, so I'm having issues with decrypting all the usernames to compare with the new decrypted username to be registered to check if it already exists.

Comment: @FUBAR The existing answers explain that problem.  SO tip: adding an @ before someone's name will notify them that you replied to them.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: @FUBAR Does "duplicate" mean that the user is registered? If yes, then remove the *not* from the `if` condition and see if it solves your problem. If it does, then this is a simple typo question and should be deleted.

Comment: @ArtjomB it doesn't solve the problem. I think my naming of that boolean has confused you. By "isRegistered" I'm not using that as to say yes, this person is registered now because the username is unique, the idea of this boolean was to be sent as true if the username is unique and added to the system, or false if the username has been taken. So in my IF that you're talking about it's checking if the username doesn't exist in the ArrayList, which would be true, so that user can then be registered by adding it to the ArrayList. I'll try the provided answers.

Comment: @FUBAR Please [edit] your question to add this clarification and change the variable name.

Comment: Why are you encrypting usernames at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
String dUsername = aes.decrypt(eUsername);
boolean isRegistered = false;

List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
for (Users users : usersList) {
    temp.add(aes.decrypt(users.getUsername()));
}

for (String usernames : temp) {
    if (usernames.equals(dUsername)) {
        isRegistered = true;
        break;
    }
}

return !isRegistered;
```

Note the negation of the condition in the loop and that the result is negated at the end. If you have more than one user in `userList`, you will obviously always have at least one user where the condition `!usernames.equals(dUsername)` is true in which case `isRegistered` will set to `true` and can never go back when the actual duplicate is found. So you need to look *only* for the duplicate in this list, because it is a one time event.
After that, you can negate the result to signalize that the checked username was unique.

It seems that you successfully decrypted the usernames by iterating over `usersList`. Since you're only interested in finding one duplicate (and the usernames are supposed to be unique), you can merge those two loops into one to improve efficiency:

```
String dUsername = aes.decrypt(eUsername);
boolean isRegistered = false;

for (Users users : usersList) {
    String uname = aes.decrypt(users.getUsername());
    if (uname.equals(dUsername)) {
        isRegistered = true;
        break;
    }
}

return !isRegistered;
```

Comment: Why bother looping at all? Couldn't the whole mess be done with a `Set` and a single call to `contains`? Or in fact `return userList.stream().map(User::getUsername).map(aes::decrypt).noneMatch(dUsername::equals);`

Answer (score 0):

Is it always returning "true" showing user is already registered?  Because I think maybe you want:

```
if (usernames.equals(dUsername))   
        isRegistered = true;
```

Comment: ...or replace:

for (String usernames : temp) {
    if (!usernames.equals(dUsername))   
        isRegistered = true;
}

With a simple: 

if (temp.contains(dUsername))  isRegistered = true;

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're encrypting usernames at all, but it isn't necessary to decrypt them at all to compare them. Just compare the encrypted usernames.

Comment: Provided ECB mode or CBC/CTR mode with constant IV is used.